# How can I iterate through nested nested documents in mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, coldfusion

Let's say I have a document structure like this:

```
{
    "product123_types": {
        "type_1": {
            "settings": {
                "name": "something",
                "success": "600,400,500,800"
            }
        }
    },
    "product345_types": {
        "type_1": {
            "settings": {
                "name": "something",
                "success": "500,400"
            }
        },
        "type_2": {
            "settings": {
                "name": "another one",
                "success": "500,800,700"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pull out the `success` values from all `type` entries? The `product` value will always have the same schema, so I was thinking of a wildcard to iterate through all the `products`, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

The ultimate goal is to convert the `success` values to different ones based on another lookup table. They are comma separated, which adds another level of difficulty, but if I can at least drill down to all the success values for each type for each product, that would be a good start.

EDIT: I originally wanted a way to get the success values via Robo 3T or similar software, but a ColdFusion solution would work as well.

Comment: You can't find an answer because you ask a wrong question. Mongo is document-oriented database. It let you iterate over documents. Iterating over properties of the document is totally on your application, but you don't even specify the language. There is map-reduce and aggregation framework that allow you to run some logic on db side. Take a look if it suffice.

Comment: is there a way to use a wildcard for the top level document name? not using any programming language, just using "find" - I'm using Robo 3T.

Comment: no, find is to find documents. $unwind won't help either - it's for arrays. "not using any programming language" is not quite true either. Mongo shell and Robo 3T using javascript, which is basically interactive application. You can always use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate document's properties or use aggregation with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and do the same serverside.

Comment: ok. how about using the openbd flavor of ColdFusion?

Comment: Hmmm, what about it? Is it related to the question in any way?

Comment: I would imagine so. The thing is if you don't mention ColdFusion in the question nor tag it accordingly, the chances that people who know ColdFusion can notice the question are very low. Please don't assume people know context of your question. All we see is only what you have asked. I won't comment on the last bit - human feelings are definitely off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

## ColdFusion solution

I've added comments in the code for you.

```
<cfscript>

    docFromDB = '{
        "product123_types": {
            "type_1": {
                "settings": {
                    "name": "something",
                    "success": "600,400,500,800"
                }
            }
        },
        "product345_types": {
            "type_1": {
                "settings": {
                    "name": "something",
                    "success": "500,400"
                }
            },
            "type_2": {
                "settings": {
                    "name": "another one",
                    "success": "500,800,700"
                }
            }
        }
    }'; // assuming you are fetching the JSON as string from the database

    // deserialize JSON string from database
    docFromDB = deserializeJSON(docFromDB);

    // iterate over each entry in the JSON
    for (key in docFromDB) {

        // skip all keys that do not match our pattern "productN_types"
        if (!reFind("^product[0-9]+_types$", key)) {
            continue;
        }

        // alias to reference the "productN_types" node
        productNode = docFromDB[key];

        // iterate over each entry in the "productN_types" node
        for (key in productNode) {

            // skip all keys that do not match our pattern "type_N"
            if (!reFind("^type_[0-9]+$", key)) {
                break;
            }

            // alias to reference the "type_N" node in the "productN_types" node
            typeNode = productNode[key];

            // skip node if there is no "settings" key in it
            if (!structKeyExists(typeNode, "settings")) {
                break;
            }

            // alias to reference the "settings" node in the "type_N" node of the "productN_types" node
            settingsNode = typeNode["settings"];

            // skip node if there is no "success" key in it
            if (!structKeyExists(settingsNode, "success")) {
                break;
            }

            // success values as "list" (comma separated)
            successValueList = settingsNode["success"];

            // success values as "array"
            successValueArray = listToArray(successValueList); // exactly what String.split(',') in JS does

            // iterate over each success value (we are using "i" to reference the entry later)
            i = 1;
            for (successValue in successValueArray) {

                // do your actual lookup, I'm just mocking something here
                if (successValue == "400") {

                    // we are using the current index "i" to overwrite the array value,
                    // because "successValue" is just a flat copy here
                    successValueArray[i] = "fourhundred";
                }

                i++;
            }

            // write back your modified success values,
            // "settingsNode" is a reference, so we can simply overwrite it
            settingsNode["success"] = arrayToList(successValueArray); // exactly what String.join(',') in JS does
        }
    }

    // your result
    writeDump(docFromDB);

</cfscript>
```